# SQL-Server: Store Ω (Omega) in a nvarchar field

Tags: sql-server, encoding, special-characters

If I run

```
create table t (c nvarchar(10));

insert into t (c) 
values ('Ω');

select * from t
```

the output is O

```
O
```

instead of Omega

```
Ω
```

I thought I could store almost every character in a `nvarchar` field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `N` before the character:

```
insert into t (c) 
values (N'Ω');
```